# Who said Moses is a magician and asked for commands?

Tags: quran, tafseer

It seems that verses 34-36 of the surah Ash-Shu'ara (26) are not compatible with verses 109-111 from the surah Al-A'raf (7).

In 26, Pharaoh says so. In 7, the great leaders say so.

What is the explanation here?

Answer (score 0):

> [7:109] **The council of Pharaoh’s folk said, ‘Surely this man is a cunning sorcerer,** outstanding in the art
> of magic, in [sūrat] al-Shuʿarāʾ [Q. 26:34], these are actually Pharaoh’s words, and so it is as if they said
> it in consultation with him,
>
> <sup>[Tafsir Al-Jalalayn 7:109](https://archive.org/details/AlJalalainEng/page/n173/mode/1up)</sup>

So either both the Pharaoh and his council said it or the council were just agreeing with Pharaoh after he explicitly said the words in Quran 26:34.

Another tafsir that contains this view is found in
[Tafsir Ibn Ajiba](https://shamela.ws/book/10273/838#p1).

Answer (score 0):

Both of them said it.

> The chiefs and noblemen of the people of Fir'awn agreed with Fir'awn's
> statement about Musa. After Fir`awn felt safe and returned to his
> throne, he said to the chiefs of his people, إِنَّ هَـذَا لَسَـحِرٌ
> عَلِيمٌ
>
> (This is indeed a well-versed sorcerer) and they agreed.

https://quran.com/ms/7:109/tafsirs/en-tafisr-ibn-kathir

Example the president of country says something, then members of his cabinet also repeat the same thing because they share same opinion.